# Minimal ROS2 Python package

Tags: ros, ros2, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How looks the structure and the content of a plain ROS2 library level package? The intent of the package is to encapsulate functionality implemented in Python which can be imported into other ROS2 packages.

- no ROS2 dependency (despite for building, linting, etc.)
- no scripts
- no nodes
- no docs
- no tests just plain ament linter checks (copyright, flake8, pep257)

**EDIT:** [Draft on GitHub.](https://github.com/fkromer/examples/tree/minimal_python_package/rclpy/packages/minimal_package)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274972/minimal-ros2-python-package/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-08-18**:
Will be obsolete as soon as https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/125 is implemented.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-10-09**:
How are Python package dependencies managed in ROS2? I could just find an example where [an install_requires dependency](https://github.com/Misterblue/ros2_adafruit_pwmhat_node/blob/master/src/ros2/ros2_adafruit_pwmhat_node/setup.py#L35) is assumed to be pre-installed via `setup.py install` or PyPi.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-10-21**:
In this case there shouldn't be any limitations w.r.t. Python packaging (Pipfile, etc.) right?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-22**:
I don't think so. So long as the alternative mechanism (pipfile or requirements.txt or whatever) will avoid installing things that are already installed by the system package manager (like apt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will work just like any `setup.py` file works. However, if you want to release it in our infrastructure you'll want to duplicate the entries in the `package.xml` and ensure there are rosdep rules for it. This would allow for dependencies to be fetch from something other than pip, like apt.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1